# Topological sort in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a data type Graph which looks like this:

```
data Graph w = Graph {vertices :: [(Char, w)],
                      edges :: [(Char, Char, w)]} deriving Show
```

This is representing a directed acyclic graph. Where vertices have a char identifier ('a' for the first vertice added, 'b' for the second and so on) and a weight. Edges are two vertice identifiers and a weight.

I'm thinking about making the vertices a bit more complex, maybe they should contain a list of all neighbours?

The topological ordering looks like this so far:

```
topological_ordering :: Graph w -> [Char]
topological_ordering (Graph v w) =
    let startingNodes = getStartNodes (Graph v w)
        emptyList = []
        sorted = sortAlgorithm startingNodes emptyList (Graph v w)
    in sorted

sortAlgorithm :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Graph w -> [Char]
sortAlgorithm startingNodes sorted (Graph v w) =
    | [] _ _ = []
    | (x:startingNodes) sorted (Graph v w) =
      let sorted = sorted ++ [x]
          neigbours = findNeighbours (Graph v w) x

getStartNodes :: Graph w -> [Char]
getStartNodes (Graph v w) =
    let set1 = Set.fromList $ firstNodes w
        set2 = Set.fromList $ secondNodes w
        startNodes = Set.toList $ Set.difference set1 set2
    in  startNodes

firstNodes :: [(Char, Char, w)] -> [Char]
firstNodes [] = []
firstNodes (x:xs) = selectFirst x:firstNodes xs

secondNodes :: [(Char, Char, w)] -> [Char]
secondNodes [] = []
secondNodes (x:xs) = selectSecond x:secondNodes xs
```

From there I'm a little lost. I don't really know how to complete the sortAlgorithm, because I want it to be recursive (or use foldl/foldr?). Should implement the data type for Graph in another way or should I continue with this?

I just started haskell a few weeks ago and still feel a bit lost on functional programming.

Thanks

Comment: Since your graph is always acyclic, I wonder is it possible to represent it using ADTs rather than lists of vertices and edges?

Comment: Well if I have a simple graph like a -> b -> c I would need a list with vertices [(a, 5), (b, 3), (c, 4)] and edges [(a,b,10), (b,c,5)].
Where the numbers a weights

Comment: @user2894391 Directed acyclic doesn't mean tree. You'd still need to [tie the knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) which is a little brittle if you plan on serialising/deserialising etc, but OK if you're just in memory at runtime.

Comment: @enoughreptocomment First, I didn't mention anything about trees. Second, knot tying (self-references) is only needed for cyclic data.

Comment: @user2894391 An ADT _is_ a tree. An acyclic directed graph can be a topological cycle even if it has no path cycle. Suppose we have vertices 1,2,3,4,5 and edges (1,2) (2,4)  (1,3) (3,4)  (4,5). If you try to represent it as an ADT without tying a knot, you'll have two vertices labelled 4.

Comment: @enoughreptocomment There is no exact definition of 'tying the knot' at the haskellwiki. But the whole article there is about self-referenced data structures, so I suppose 'tying the knot' term is only applicable to cases where strict evaluation will go to an infinite loop. In your example even a strict program will terminate.

Comment: @user2894391 Terminate with incorrect results isn't actually a good thing in my view. Example: sum or average edge length, most folds, traversals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a solid algorithmic approach how to tackle topological sort? There are different possibilities; the two best-known are probably the following:

- Do a DFS on the graph and sort the vertices according to their finish time in descending order. So: If you already have DFS, adapt it do output finish times and sort vertices in descending order.
- The other approach requires you to store the number of incoming, not-yet-processed edges into each vertex (this possibly requires some preprocessing, usually one graph traversal - let's call the corresponding field for each vertex the "edge counter"). Starting nodes - of course - have edge counter = 0. As the next vertex, you can only pick those whose edge counter is set to 0. If you encounter an edge `(a,b,w)`, you have to decrement the edge counter of `b` by 1.

  Note that this second approach can be implemented in a way such you have a list `candidates` that is initially only filled with the starting nodes. As soon as you decrement the edge counter of `b` and see that it is now 0, you add `b` to the `candidates`. In the next step, you pick the head of `candidates` as the next vertex to process.

  To store the edge count, you could use e.g. a [HashMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap-1.0.0.2/docs/Data-HashMap.html).

Here some (non-haskell, but probably-close-to-haskell) inspiration for the second approach:

```
sortAlgorithm startingNodes sorted (Graph v w) edgeCounts =
    | [] _ _ = sorted    -- processed all nodes? => output result
    | (x:remainingNodes) sorted (Graph v w) =
      let newEdgeCounts = foldl 
          (\ec (a, b, w) -> Data.HashMap.insert ((Data.HashMap.findWithDefault 0 b ec) - 1) ec)
      in sortAlgorithm remainingNodes (sorted ++ [x]) newEdgeCounts
```

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this algorithm:
    while startingNodes is non empty 
        remove a node n from startingNodes
        add n to tail of sorted
        for each node m with an edge e from n to m 
            remove edge e from graph
            if m has no onther incoming edges
                insert m into startingNodes

It's straight from wikipedia so I don't know if its suitable for haskell but I guess it should work. Would it be better to use one of the two you described? 

Thanks

Comment: No, your approach is good enough I think. You just need to store the mentioned "edge count" somewhere (e.g. HashMap).

Answer (score 9):

You might want to take a look at how elegantly it is done in [Data.Graph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.2.0.1/docs/src/Data-Graph.html#topSort). Here is an outline of the algorithm:

```
topSort      :: Graph -> [Vertex]
topSort       = reverse . postOrd

postOrd      :: Graph -> [Vertex]
postOrd       = postorderF . dff

postorder :: Tree a -> [a]
postorder (Node a ts) = postorderF ts ++ [a]

postorderF   :: Forest a -> [a]
postorderF ts = concat (map postorder ts)

-- | A spanning forest of the graph, obtained from a depth-first search of
-- the graph starting from each vertex in an unspecified order.
dff          :: Graph -> Forest Vertex
dff g         = dfs g (vertices g)

-- | A spanning forest of the part of the graph reachable from the listed
-- vertices, obtained from a depth-first search of the graph starting at
-- each of the listed vertices in order.
dfs          :: Graph -> [Vertex] -> Forest Vertex
```

That is, a topological sort of a graph is (the reverse of) a post-order traversal of a spanning forest of the graph.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
  import qualified Data.Graph as G

  {-
     5 --> 7
     |     |
     v     V
     1 --> 4 --> 8
  -}

  (myGraph,vertexToNode,keyToVertex) = G.graphFromEdges [
      ("node4",4,[8]),     -- the first component can be of any type
      ("node8",8,[]),
      ("node7",7,[4]),
      ("node5",5,[1,7]),
      ("node1",1,[4])
   ]

  sorted = map vertexToNode $ G.topSort myGraph
  -- [("node5",5,[1,7]),("node7",7,[4]),("node1",1,[4]),("node4",4,[8]),("node8",8,[])]
```

Comment: What's the complexity of Data.Graph's topSort?

Comment: @egdmitry the erlang implementation is linear and it uses the same algorithm